# WPF: TextBox resizes inside ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I have a TextBox that stretches to the width of the window:

```
<Window ...>
    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Window>
```

However, the textbox should have a minimum width, and I want scroll bars to be shown, if the textbox cannot be displayed fully. Thus:

```
<Window ...>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox MinWidth="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

This, however, has a negative side effect. If the user enters more text than fits into the text box, the text box increases its size:

[alt text http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/8093/33086888.png](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/8093/33086888.png)

Is there a way to avoid this effect and still have the scroll bars if the minimum size of the textbox is reached?